# Div section with fixed background not showing in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

This div with a fixed background shows fine in both Safari and Chrome, but not in Firefox. I try to find why but without luck.
Thank you in advice!

**HTML**

```
<div class="fixed-section fixed-bg-1">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fixed-section {
    min-height: 50%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
}

.fixed-section.fixed-bg-1 {
    background-image: url("../images/slider-00.png");
}
.overlay {
    background: transparent url("../images/overlays/overlay-01.png"); 
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 0; 

    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to a demo site with above codes?? If no, can you provide the above in a jsfiddle

Comment: The site is http://www.timemachineliverocktribute.it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `height:50%;` to your fixed-section class along with your min-height like this:

```
.fixed-section {
    height: 50%;
    min-height: 50%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 z-index properties in your overlay. More than likely one Safari/Chrome/Firefox read them in different orders.

Eg : 
Safari/Chrome - z-index:0 then z-index:3
Firefox- z-index:3 then z-index: 0

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this is the case?

Comment: @Paulie_D best way to know, I guess, is to remove one and see if it solves the case. If it does, then we can go wild and test all possibilities to see which browsers does what.

Comment: Properties are parsed in the order they are given...this has been the case for many years. If 3 comes after 0, then 3 applies.

Comment: Sorry but the copy-paste adds another z-index. I try to remove the z-index property and also the overlay class but nothing to do. In firefox the div doesn't appear